# How do I capture/mock outbound requests from tests written in Geb/Spock?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

We have a scenario where we are running our application on say `app.local:3000` and typically calls endpoints at `app.local:3000/api`.

In the source code, the request is made with Javascript with a relative url `/api` (ie. app.local:3000 is not within the source code).

During tests, we would like to capture/mock/stub all requests to `app.local:3000/api` and instead point it to a mock server we have called `mock.local:3000/api`.

Is it possible for Geb or Spock to capture and remap outbound requests?

- We can't alter the implementation code (there are 100's of different pieces of code hitting the endpoint, all using relative links)
- I have tried baseUrl in Geb but it doesn't appear to alter outbound requests
- I have tried using `js.exec` to overwrite the html base tag, but the script executes too late

Comment: I have a hard time understanding how this is a Geb or Spock question. So would you please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ("M" meaning minimal) reproducing the described behaviour? Something to test against? Thank you so much. BTW, a mock should be reachable under the normal URI and just replace the normal API. Then you would not need any black re-routing magic. A router or a facade is not a mock. It is more of a spy sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to remap outbound requests using Spock or Geb alone.

In my own test suite I use a dockerd nginx (["nginx" from official repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)) as a proxy, controlled by [testcontainers-spock](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-spock).

Excerpt from nginx config

```
location /api {
    # rewrite path
    rewrite /api /api-on-mock break;
    # proxy to the mock
    proxy_pass http://mock;
}
location @other {
    proxy_pass https://original;
}
```

We then run all tests against the proxy.

I have heard a lot of good things about [betamax](https://github.com/betamaxteam/betamax) but not used it myself.